# Generate new username and check if already exist

Tags: php

I need to generate unique username automatically, I've created two functions, one to create a random username and the other one to check if the username is already stored in the database. Do you think these two functions can work?

```
function km_create_random_username($db_user_conn){

  //set the random id length 
  $km_random_username_length = 6; 
  //generate a random id encrypt it and store it in $rnd_id 
  $km_random_username = uniqid(rand(),1); 
  //to remove any slashes that might have come 
  $km_random_username = strip_tags(stripslashes($km_random_username)); 
  //Removing any . or / and reversing the string 
  $km_random_username = str_replace(".","",$km_random_username); 
  $km_random_username = strrev(str_replace("/","",$km_random_username)); 
  //finally I take the first 6 characters from the $km_rnd_id 
  $km_random_username = substr($km_random_username,0,$km_random_username_length); 

  if(!km_check_random_username($db_user_conn, $km_random_username)){
    return $km_random_username;
  }

}


function km_check_random_username($db_user_conn, $km_random_username) {

  $query = "SELECT km_user_username FROM km_users WHERE km_user_username=?";
  $stmt = mysqli_prepare($db_user_conn, $query);
  mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 's', $km_random_username);
  mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
  mysqli_stmt_store_result($stmt);
  $rows = mysqli_stmt_num_rows($stmt);
  mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt);

  if($rows > 0) {

    km_create_random_username($db_user_conn);

  }else{

    return false;

  }

}
```

Comment: Hi @RiggsFolly yes I don't know how to test it because it will be impossible to find a matching username considering the large amount of combination the function km_create_random_username does create

Comment: Well if you are ___right___ about it being Impossible ..... have you not answered your own question :)

Comment: :) Yes but how can I test if in the unfortunate event of username already stored then a new one will be created?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To test that the code spots duplicates and then generates a new randon username do this.

1. Either empty the table `km_user` or record the last `id` value
2. Run the `km_check_random_username()` function twice manually passing the same username both time.

   ```
   km_check_random_username($db_user_conn, 'ItsMee');
   km_check_random_username($db_user_conn, 'ItsMee');
   ```
3. Check the table? Did it create the `ItsMee` username?
4. Did it create a random `username` after creating the `ItsMe` username? If it did, then it spotted the Dup and ran the regenerate phase

Comment: well, it is nearly Christmas ;-)

Comment: I've just used km_check_random_username($db_user_conn, 'ItsMee'); once after I've changed the username stored in the database to  'ItsMee' and it seem to work, it does change it to the new random username. It seems to work fine, thanks for your support. The way I would use it though is with km_create_random_username($db_user_conn)

Answer (score 0):

```
echo gen_random_username(10);
// generates jPMNfrQZil
function gen_random_username($db_user_conn, $length){
    $chars = "0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
    $random_username = "";
    for($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++){
        $random_username .= $chars[rand(0,strlen($chars)-1)];
    }
    if(!km_check_random_username($db_user_conn, $random_username)){
        return $random_username;
      }
}
// I didn't check this function, but I modified it to use the above function
// gen_random_username($x, $length)...
function km_check_random_username($db_user_conn, $km_random_username) {

  $query = "SELECT km_user_username FROM km_users WHERE km_user_username=?";
  $stmt = mysqli_prepare($db_user_conn, $query);
  mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 's', $km_random_username);
  mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
  mysqli_stmt_store_result($stmt);
  $rows = mysqli_stmt_num_rows($stmt);
  mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt);

  if($rows > 0) {

    gen_random_username($db_user_conn, 10);

  }else{

    return false;

  }
```

Comment: Hi @Safi not sure this is what I asked but another way to generate random usernames. Thanoks anyway